# Перевод длинного двоичного кода в десятичное число в виде строки

Tags: c++, алгоритм, системы-счисления

Есть bitset, скажем, размерности 1000. Задача состоит в том, что нужно вывести это число на экран в десятичной системе. Поскольку такое число не влезет ни в один встроенный численный тип, то необходимо преобразовать его в строку (string, const char* - не важно). Какие есть варианты решения? Приходит в голову только длинная арифметика, но хотелось бы какой-то более приятный вариант.

Comment: Так вам на экран вывести надо, или производить арифметические операции прямо в строковом представлении?

Comment: Определите для своего битсета операторы `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, и используйте стандартный алгоритм преобразования в строку.

Comment: `std::cout << b; | python3 -c "print(int(input(), 2))"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

«более приятный вариант» в данном случае это использовать готовую библиотеку, вместо того чтобы реализовывать арифметику высокой точности руками.

Чтобы вывести `std::bitset<>` на экран в десятичной системе, можно воспользоваться [GMP библиотекой](https://gmplib.org/):

```
#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>
#include <gmp.h>

int main()
{
  std::bitset<70> b;
  b[66] = 1;
  std::cout << b << std::endl;

  mpz_t z;
  mpz_init_set_str(z, b.to_string().c_str(), 2);
  std::cout << z << std::endl;
  mpz_clear(z);
}
```

Пример:

```
$ g++ main.cc -o main -lgmpxx -lgmp 
$ ./main
```

Вывод:

```
0001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
73786976294838206464
```

GMP не использует квадратичный алгоритм для перевода в десятичную систему, поэтому можно печатать хоть числа с миллионом цифр. Related: [Writing huge strings in python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28480239/4279).

Конечно, можно напрямую манипулировать битами, используя GMP, без `std::bitset<>`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <gmp.h>

int main()
{
  mpz_t b;
  mpz_init(b);
  mpz_setbit(b, 66);
  std::cout << b << std::endl;
  mpz_clear(b);
}
```

Вывод:

```
73786976294838206464
```

Answer (score 0):

Почему бы не использовать массив, скажем, unsigned long? Использование строки - заведомо тупиковый путь, если учесть, что это числа, а значит наверняка придётся производить какие-либо арифметические и прочие операции.

Comment: 1000 бит не поместится в 64-битный unsigned, с 19 августа этот вопрос не менялся. этот ответ не отвечает на вопрос.